# How to go to first line of a function if a condition is not satisfied in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to got First line of the function `goToSignUpActivit()` if `isAllInputValid == False`

```
from CustomUtil import *
from Register import *
def goToSingUpActivity():
    fName = input("Enter your First Name:")    
    lName = input("Enter your last name:")

    mobileNum = input("input your mobile number")

    role  =  input("Select your role  s: for staff p: for patient:")

    isFNameValid = validateInput(fName)
    isLNameValid = validateInput(lName) // this function in CustomUtil package
    isRoleValid = False
    if (role in ["s","p","S","P"]):
        isRoleValid = True
    isMobileNumValid = validateMobilNum(mobileNum)// this function in CustomUtil package

    isAllInputValid = False
    if  (isFNameValid and isLNameValid and isRoleValid and isMobileNumValid) :
         isAllInputValid = True


    if  (isAllInputValid) :
        isAllInputValid = True
        if role in ["s","S"]:

            registerAsStaff(fName,lName,mobileNum)// this function in Register package    
            return
        elif role in ["p","P"]:

            registerAsPatient(fName,lName,mobileNum)// this function in Register package
            return
    while(not isAllInputValid):
        if(input("you want to exit y or n:") in ["y","Y"]):
            return
        goToSingUpActivity()
```

Above code put `goToSingUpActivity()` into the stack while `isAllInputValid` become true.
After I enter all input correctly stack pop  `goToSingUpActivity()` one bye one.

What I need here is after `isAllInputValid` becomes true, clear all `goToSingUpActivity()` from stack.

If above solution not possible, is there any other way to modifie the code?

Edit: I got a solution by making  `isAllInputValid` global and put the while loop outside the function after calling `goToSingUpActivity()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while statement (WARNING to don't create a `while(true)`, give to the user an opportunity to cancel his action !).

```
def goToSingUpActivity():
 isAllValid = False
 while(!isAllValid):
  #your inputs stuff
  if(isFNameValid and isLNameValid and isRoleValid and isMobileNumValid):
   isAllValid = True
 #rest of the function
```